# Prove that if $d|a$, then $-d|a$ and $d|-a$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-verification, proof-writing

> Prove that if $d|a$, then $-d|a$ and $d|-a$
>
> Additionally $d| |a|$.

I wouldn't mind someone going over the correctness of my proof if they have time please.

If $d|a$, then there is some integer $k$, such that $dk=a$

Also $-d(-k)=a$ so $-d|a$

Also $d(-k)=-a$ so $d|-a$

$d|0$, so that $d||a|$.

Apart from potentially missing something in logic, I'm sure this could be written in correct mathematical english a little better if someone has some input that would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Thanks for helping me with formatting @lioness99a.

Comment: Your first three are absolutely perfect.  However your last $d|0$ therefore $d||a|$ is utterly incomprehensible and makes no sense to me whatsoever.  What does dividing into zero (which *every* number does) have to do with dividing into the absolute value of a.  As *every* number divides into zero you can not use it to prove anything that isn't true for *every* number and not all numbers divide |a| so d|0 can't prove d||a| any more than 1847|0 can be used to prove 1847|256.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your argument is just fine (most of the way). There's no neater way, no better "mathematical English", than your case by case treatment.

For $d | |a|$ you should do cases too: the absolute value of $a$ is always either $a$ or $-a$ so your first argument covers it.

No need to treat $0$ as a special case. Indeed, everything divides $0$.

Comment: Ok thanks for the feedback @Ethan. I will drop the 0 in similar instances in the future.

Answer (score 1):

Your first three are absolutely perfect. However your last $d|0$ therefore $d||a|$ is utterly incomprehensible and makes no sense to me whatsoever. What does dividing into zero (which every number does) have to do with dividing into the absolute value of a. As every number divides into zero you can not use it to prove anything that isn't true for every number and not all numbers divide $|a|$ so $d|0$ can't prove $d||a|$ any more than $1847|0$ can be used to prove $1847|256$.

Instead simply say, As $|a| = \pm a$ and we have been given $d|a$ and we have proven $d|-a$ therefore $d||a|$ no matter whether $|a| = a$ or $|a| = -a$.

.....

Oh... I see.  You were assuming it was clear you were doing three cases.  If $a > 0$ then then $d|a \implies d||a|$.  If $a < 0$ then $d|-a \implies d||a|$ and if $a = 0$ then $d|0 \implies d||a|$.  That would have been fine except it wasn't clear that that was your intent.

At least,  I completely missed it.

But you don't need to specifically show the case for $a=0$ because if $a = 0$ then $|a| = a$ and that was covered in the given case.

Comment: Yes, that was my intention, it was cumulative on the preceding two statements. I'm a learner driver with math communication.

Comment: Ok, I will keep that in mind that if $a=0$ then $|a|=a$ for future.

Comment: Your proof was good.  I just didn't realize what you were intending.  Doing a case for $a = 0$ isn't *wrong* per se and sometimes it is the right way to go.  I just didn't understand your intent.